# Do I use the suffix -ist or -istic in adjectival forms of words that end in -ism

Tags: adjectives, suffixes

So basically, I want to use the word infallibilism in its adjectival form and I don't whether to write infallibilist or infallibilistic. I have to say the former sounds better for some reason.

An easier example may be with minimalism. Is it "Joe's idea of decorating a room is very minimalist" or "Joe's idea of decorating a room is very minimalistic".

An answer I anticipate is that both are possible, but I would like to know what exactly the difference is, for there must be a difference, if ever so subtle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are some "-ist" suffixed words used as the adjective form over the more common "-istic"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/220753/why-are-some-ist-suffixed-words-used-as-the-adjective-form-over-the-more-comm)

Answer (score 1):

I would posit that -istic is *usually* an adjective, while -ist is *usually* a noun.

Comment: ***Heuristic*** can certainly be used as a noun. And ***statistic*** is *always* a noun.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Excellent points! My theory lasted 5 minutes... haha! I will revise...

Comment: Don't concede defeat too soon! They were the only two examples I could think of, and neither of them are "regularly-formed" in the same way as, say, ***artistic, realistic*** (where ***art, real*** are genuine "root" words; ***heur, stat*** just aren't like that).

Comment: **_heur_** and **_stat_** do seem like outliers, but I changed "always" to "usually" in the first part of my answer. Good find!